# PHP For loop iteration should adjust

Tags: php, html

I have a for loop designed to extract all the numbers from varying strings I supply to it. I am saving the extracted numbers in an array. My code is as follows:

```
$length = strlen($RouteString); 
$data = [];
$index = 0;     
for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++)
{           
    $j = 1;
    $count = 0;
    while(is_numeric(substr($RouteString,$i,$j)) == true)
    {
        $data[$index] = substr($RouteString,$i,$j);
        $j = $j+1;          
    }

    if(is_numeric(substr($RouteString,$i,1)) == true)
    {
        $index = $index + 1;
    }
}
```

`$Routestring` is set as: `"B12-1234-U102-D4-11-19-E"` and should give the results of `$data=[12,1234,102,4,11,19]` but instead it gives `$data=[12,2,1234,234,34,4,102,02,2,4,11,1,19,9]`.

I have tried fixing the problem by adjusting the `$index` but it doesn't work. I can't figure out how to fix this.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Would it work if you just replaced all non numbers with a single pipe, then exploded by the pipes? I think that might be a better, quicker approach to the issue, but obviously does not answer your question as it currently is.

Comment: @zbee I tried your method but it creates empty array entries, That's the same reason I used the $index in my code instead of $i.

Comment: See abraCadaver's answer for what I had meant. It returns exactly what you said you were aiming for, but in a much more concise manner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to do this easier, here is one:

```
preg_match_all('/\d+/', $string, $matches);
```

Match on 1 or more digits `\d+`. Your array will be in `$matches[0]`.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

If there's no other variables involved, this should work:

*UPDATED*

```
$str = "B12-1234-U102-D4-11-19-E";
$result = preg_split("/\D/", $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

Comment: Please explain your usage of `preg_split()`.

Comment: I tried this method that you suggested but it creates empty array entries, That's the same reason I used the $index in my code instead of $i.

Comment: There is a `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY` flag but `preg_split` is probably not the best tool for this job.

Comment: @Stephan can you show your code that is producing empty array entries? Both this code and that in the other answer provide the result set you said you were trying to attain.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it:

```php
$str = 'B12-1234-U102-D4-11-19-E';
$data = array_map('intval', array_filter(preg_split("/\D+/", $str)));
```

- `preg_split` will return an array with only numbers.
- `array_filter` will remove all the nulls from the result.
- `array_map` will transform all the results to integers.

And if you have a problem with the keys you can use `array_values` to reset them.

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1c28b9e4ba29c003e4cbcc5c5421abe7f0d98db8)